# How to unit test a service that needs localStorage without mocking it in Angular

Tags: angular, jasmine, local-storage, karma-runner

Let's say I have a service that uses html5 **localStorage**. As a global object I am able to use it in Angular like this:

in app.module I declare a type:

```
export declare let localStorage: any;
```

Then I can import this in the service and use it just fine.
Now when I test it using Jasmine and karma, **localStorage** in undefined. From my understanding karma will lunch an instance of Chrome and run the test in Chrome, as such **localStorage** should be available.

Note that I can wrap this in a service and inject it but I don't want to do that. If the test is running in the browser then I should be able to access **localStorage**. What I am missing here?

Comment: *Note that I can wrap this in a service and inject* - and it would be the right thing to do. 'don't want to do that' doesn't sound like a good reason to me. There are two options, you can make `localStorage` injectable, or you can make `window` injectable and refer to local storage as `window.localStorage` everywhere.

Comment: when I said I don't want to do that it was just to make a proof of concept as the test is running in the browser then I should be able to access localStorage. thank you for your comment

Comment: It is considered a best practice to mock it in unit tests. But yes, real localStorage should be available in real browser, there's no good explanation why it is undefined. Make sure that Chrome is used and not Phantomjs, although it is likely available in Phantomjs, too.

Comment: General rule, don't mock what you don't own. So in my case when I use localStorage, it is only for the unit test.  you can always add a localStorage.clear() using afterTest etc.